# Original visa application says I want to stay in the UK for 1 week. Can I extend this to 1 month after my visa is issued?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, application-status

I applied for a UK Visit visa and indicated that I would be staying for 1 week due to university commitments. After that, I realised I could spend one month instead of one week, What can I do to fix that?

For a 1-week visa application, is it going to be exactly one week or a little bit more to allow me to stay longer?

It would really be disappointing that I could have 1 month but stay for one week!

Comment: edit: I already submitted my application and is currently in process.

Comment: The Standard Visitor Visa is issued for 6 months except in massively rare situations like court appearances and so forth

Comment: but I stated that my stay would be for 1 week. Is it going to be issued for only one week? or of a standard minimum or the max 6 months?

Comment: You are having 'post-submission anxiety' and there is totally no way to change anything or curative fix until you receive your passport and examine the entry clearance therein (or refusal stamp whichever applies).

Comment: Indeed. It is my first ever visa application and I did it on my own.
I have no reason to be worried about a refusal but worried about the duration I will have. Thank you.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to stay for a month instead of a week?

Comment: Have you received your visa?

Answer (score 3):

> I applied for a UK Visit visa and indicated that I would be staying
>   for 1 week due to university commitments. After that, I realised I
>   could spend one month instead of one week, What can I do to fix that?

There is nothing to 'fix', the 'standard visitor visa' is issued for a term of six months and very rarely (if ever) is this changed. I haven't seen one issued for less than 6 months since the visa was invented in 2015.  They like to keep it 'standard' because it reduces the overhead costs.

> For a 1-week visa application, is it going to be exactly one week or a
>   little bit more to allow me to stay longer?

The only time they issue 1 week visas is when the person needs to testify in court or when the person has a performance engagement under the Tier 5 programme. These do not apply to you.

Some things to consider...

- You may be asked to present your accommodation arrangements or proof
  of onward travel as part of your landing interview;

  If the change in your itinerary is material, you will need to advise
  the Immigration Officer during your landing interview. Failure to do
  that can lead to serious problems even if the IO did not bring it up;

  When you ultimately leave the UK, your carrier will give UKVI all of
  the details about your exit;